# Stuck on Byte Conversion

Tags: vb.net, byte

I'm trying to do a virtual click and in order to do that you need to give the `keybd_event()` a byte value in order to tell it what to do. So I have this function that takes in a passed string ( It's just a letter from A-Z ) and converts it to a byte. But when I run the program I get this error `Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'Byte' is not valid`

Here is the function:

```
Private Function getByteValue(ByVal letter As String)
    Dim byt = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(letter)
    Return byt
End Function
```

I don't know why the error is occurring, and also I'm not sure its even returning a byte value, but rather how many bytes the letter converts to, and I need a byte bvk value?

Comment: You should be declaring the datatyle the Function returns as well as the datatype of your byt variable. I suggest you always use OPTION EXPLICT to avoid hard to identify problems. Some folks like OPTION STRICT as well, which if you are dabbling in system level stuff as you are, is probably a good idea. Why are you down at this level anyway?

Answer (score 3):

`Encoding.GetBytes()` returns an *array* of bytes, not a single byte.  The error message is telling you that you are trying to convert a byte array to a byte.

You will have to iterate over the elements in the array and process each one through `keybd_event()`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method similar to what you have implemented would look like this.

```
Private Function getByteValue(ByVal letter As String) As Byte()
    Dim byt As Byte() = {}
    byt = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(letter)
    Return byt
End Function
```